# Serialization no null values

Tags: c#, serialization, null

Lets say i have a class

```
    [Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    public string model;
    public int year;
}
```

I serialize that to disk named "car.xx". Then i add a property to my Car class so it will be like this:

```
    [Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    public string model;
    public int year;
    public string colour;
}
```

Then i deserialize "car.xx" ( that contains 2 fields ) to my current car class that contains 3 fields, which will make the "colour" property of our Car class **null**.

How do i set that "**new properties**" dont get null values? Setting them in the constructor wont help.

I am using **BinaryFormatter** serializer

I want string values that are null to be replaced with ""

Comment: Have you tried just setting it like this `public string colour = "red";`?

Comment: what would you have it be? if there *is* no colour in the data?

Comment: I want it to be "" instead of null

Comment: Please be specific about which serializer you are using. `BinaryFormatter`, `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, `NetDataContractSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer`, or whatever else (third-party, etc)

Comment: (updated answer to account for `BinaryFormatter` update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are not using XmlSerializer then consider using OnDeserializedAttribute, OnSerializingAttribute, OnSerializedAttribute, and OnDeserializingAttribute attributes

see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute.aspx).

like:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Car
{
    public string colour;
    public string model;
    public int year;

    [OnDeserialized()]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
       if (colour == null)
       {
           colour = string.Empty;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the serializer.

Some serializer skip constructors; some serializers run the default constructor. Some let you choose. Some offer serialization callbacks.

So depending on the serializer:

- write a public parameterless constructor to set a default value (or use a field-initializer, which is ultimately similar)
- write an "on deserializing" serialization callback to set a default before deserialization

or worst-case, implement custom serialization (`ISerializable` / `IXmlSerializable` / etc, depending on the serializer)

For example, with `BinaryFormatter`:

```
[Serializable]
public class Car : IDeserializationCallback
{
    public string model;
    public int year;
    public string colour;
    void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        if (colour == null) colour = "";
    }
}
```

With other serializers, it might use [`[OnDeserialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) instead. Note; personally I wouldn't be exposing public fields, even in a DTO. But ***if*** you are using `BinaryFormatter`, changing this is now a breaking change. For completeness, I also wouldn't be using `BinaryFormatter` - it is *not* very friendly to this. Other serializers are available that will hurt you less.